# Why would this loop run more than once if the first attempt is successful?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, try-catch, campaign-monitor

I also tried putting the `break` right outside and after the try/catch with a `continue` inside the catch but no luck. It appears no other exceptions get thrown other than the one there.

```
do {
    try {
        $result = CM::campaigns()->create(config('campaignmonitor.client_id'), array_merge($optional_params, [
            'Subject' => $campaign->subject,
            'Name' => $campaign->client_id . ' - ' . $campaign->name . ' (' . $campaign->id . ')',
            'FromName' => $campaign->from_name,
            'FromEmail' => $campaign->from_email,
            'ReplyTo' => (!is_null($campaign->reply_email) ? $campaign->reply_email : $campaign->from_email),
            'HtmlUrl' => config('campaignmonitor.emailTemplatePath') . '/' . $campaign->html_file,
            'SegmentIDs' => [$campaign->segment_id]
        ]));

        break;
    } catch (CurlException $e) {
        // Try again
        $cmCreationTries++;
    }
} while ($cmCreationTries < 3);
```

The following does work as expected though:

```
do {
    try {
        $result = CM::campaigns()->create(config('campaignmonitor.client_id'), array_merge($optional_params, [
            'Subject' => $campaign->subject,
            'Name' => $campaign->client_id . ' - ' . $campaign->name . ' (' . $campaign->id . ')',
            'FromName' => $campaign->from_name,
            'FromEmail' => $campaign->from_email,
            'ReplyTo' => (!is_null($campaign->reply_email) ? $campaign->reply_email : $campaign->from_email),
            'HtmlUrl' => config('campaignmonitor.emailTemplatePath') . '/' . $campaign->html_file,
            'SegmentIDs' => [$campaign->segment_id]
        ]));

        // Request was successful, we can end the loop.
        $cmCreationTries = 4;
    } catch (CurlException $e) {
        // Try again
        $cmCreationTries++;
    }
} while ($cmCreationTries < 3);
```

Comment: because you don't break out of the do-while loop

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/9HDda the code only runs once if there is no Exception.
It's possible that you get an exception but the server you're talking to did process the request. Ie. you get a timeout. In that case you're going to end up with duplicate requests. There are ways to get around that, for instance by adding an identifier to the request that you re-use when you retry.

Comment: The code you provided only executes once given that no exception was thrown. You should probably log the `CurlException` to see if it occurs. Additionally I'd advice you to look into other reasons as to why this code gets executed more than once. Do you do multitple web requests? Do you call this code block more than once?

Comment: @Halcyon that's exactly what that CurlException is, a timeout.

Comment: This video explains your problem exactly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP-rGJKSZ3s